# Does node-webkit have performance issues with css filters?

Tags: css, node-webkit, css-filters

I'm currently using a css filter in a node-webkit (v0.11.2) application on Windows 7 (64 bit) like so:

```css
html {
    -webkit-filter: invert();
}
```

This works fine for the most part, but when the user maximizes the window and then attempts to drag the window, there is a huge performance lag.  The lag goes away completely without the filter.

I don't see the same performance issues in the browser, so this appears to be a node-webkit issue.

Comment: This is something that you should report on their repository. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/new

Comment: please report an issue. It should be in the same performance as in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'll make an issue.